# C++ My program is in infinite loop

Tags: visual-c++

I appreciate you taking the time to read my problem sorry I'm just a beginner in programming. Apparently I am not that good in loops and if else statement and I don't know whats wrong in my code. when I run it and input "up" its just go to (8,10). it should have been (0,1) then the console will ask which direction they want to go again. Thanks in advance!!! :D

```
#include<iostream>;
#include<string>;

using namespace std;

 int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    string input;

     cout << "objective: go to (8,9)" << endl;
     cout << "current location (" << x << "," << y << ")" << endl;

     while ( (x = 8) && (y = 9) )
{
    cout << "which way do you want to go?: ";
    cin >> input;

    if (input == "up")
    {
        ++y;
        cout << "current location (" << x << "," << y << ")" << endl;
        break;

    }
    else if (input == "down")
    {
        --y;
        cout << "current location (" << x << "," << y << ")" << endl;
        break;
    }
    else if (input == "right")
    {
        ++x;
        cout << "current location (" << x << "," << y << ")" << endl;
        break;
    }
    else if (input == "left")
    {
        --x;
        cout << "current location (" << x << "," << y << ")" << endl;
        break;
    }

}

cout << "current location (" << x << "," << y << ")" << endl;
cout << "Congratulations! You have reach your destination! :D" << endl;


system("pause");
return(0);
```

}

Comment: You're not meant to use break statements unless you want to break from the surrounding loop.

Comment: thanks I tried removing all the break but it went straight down to "congratulations! you have reach your destination" when I tried to run it and I change the condition to (x ==8) && (y ==9) still no improvement.

Comment: I suggest adding your updated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"
I tried removing all the break but it went straight down to "congratulations! you have reach your destination" when I tried to run it and I change the condition to (x ==8) && (y ==9) still no improvement.
"

Your loop condition is incorrect. The while loop will only run *if* x is 8 and y is 9. They are 0 and 0 at the beginning of the program, which explains why we skip the loop. The real condition is: "run the loop as long as x and y are *not* these values." `while (x != 8 || y != 9)` and alternately alternately: `while (!(x == 8 && y == 9))`

Comment: Oh my god! I'm getting it now how loop works so I tried ( x!=8 || y!=9) and it works! :D but I don't get it why negative number don't pop up in the console it skips all the if statements

Comment: alternately: !(x == 8 && y == 9)

Comment: Thank you! it really helped me alot. :)